# Using this trick to solve an integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I have a set of coupled integro-differential equations:
$$ \frac{dx_i(t)}{dt}=-x_i(t)+f_i(\mathbf{x}(t))+\sum_j{\partial_{x_j}f_i(\mathbf{x}(t))\int_{0}^{t}dt'f_j(\mathbf{x}(t'))e^{-(t-t')} }$$

The integrals, $ \psi_j(t) =\int_{0}^{t}dt'f_j(\mathbf{x}(t'))e^{-(t-t')} $, are solutions of the differential equations $$ \frac{d\psi_j(t)}{dt}+\psi_j(t)=f_j(\mathbf{x}(t)) $$ with $\psi(0)=0$. I've been told by my supervisor that the numerical evaluation of the coupled system can be greatly sped up by using these differential equations but I don't understand how - does anyone have any ideas? I get the feeling I'm missing something completely obvious.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical; generally numerical solution of an ODE is about as expensive as numerical integration, perhaps even a bit more expensive. It would be beneficial if it allowed you to just "update" a value from one value of $t$ to the next, but you can already do that with integration (just factor out an $e^{-t}$ from the integral). Perhaps the scaling with the $e^{-t}$ factored out is prohibitive?

Comment: Would it be useful to write $\frac{d(t\psi_j)}{dt}=f_j(t)$ and then integrate - this form for $\psi$ might be quicker?

Comment: That does not even work...you would need the integrating factor, and working with the equation with the integrating factor in place is the same as doing the integration.