# Solving an integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I have a set of coupled integro-differential equations:
$$ \frac{dx_i(t)}{dt}=-x_i(t)+f_i(\mathbf{x}(t))+\sum_j{\partial_{x_j}f_i(\mathbf{x}(t))\int_{0}^{t}dt'f_j(\mathbf{x}(t'))e^{-(t-t')} }$$

The integrals, $ \psi_j(t) =\int_{0}^{t}dt'f_j(\mathbf{x}(t'))e^{-(t-t')} $, are solutions of the differential equations $$ \frac{d\psi_j(t)}{dt}+\psi_j(t)=f_j(\mathbf{x}(t)) $$ with $\psi(0)=0$. I've been told by my supervisor that the numerical evaluation of the coupled system can be greatly sped up by using these differential equations but I don't understand how - does anyone have any ideas? I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Why don't you ask your supervisor for clarifications?

Comment: What is $f(\mathbf{x}(t))$? Is this in some way related to $x_i(t)$?

Comment: $ f(\mathbf{x}_i(t))$ is a messy function of the set $\mathbf{x}$ except $x_i(t)$

Comment: I asked my supervisor and he explained: the idea is that you solve for the system of equations ${\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\psi}}$ instead of just $\mathbf{x}$, so you have a larger system but can use standard methods. Seems obvious now -_-

Comment: Duplicate to the same unmigrated question (as of now only comments, no answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176087/using-this-trick-to-solve-an-integro-differential-equation

Comment: If it is said that it is "speed up" then what is the basis for this comparison, what would be the numerical method without this trick?

Answer (score 0):

To explain the **why** and maybe not **how** part of the question.

A differential numerical approximation:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&-1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$
**Two** non-zero values per output.
Corresponding integral numerical approximation matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$

Spreads out non-0 values all over. On average **half signal wide**.

Integrals are often nastier than derivatives numerically. An integral is global, a derivative is local. If not implemented carefully, any integrals can easily eat up all available memory and slow things down due to lots of calculations required. Instead in some cases you can pose it inversely as a derivative.